# Как лучше хранить изображения для приложения Android?

Tags: java, android

Имеется большое количество изображений маленьких размеров (500-800, ~10-20КБ каждое), мне необходимо что бы эти изображения были упакованы в apk, и приложение всегда имело доступ к этим изображениям, т.е. вариант с подключением к интернету не подходит. Как и где лучше хранить такие изображения? Как их лучше упаковать в apk?

Comment: Хранить лучше на сервере, загружать по ссылке. Это все, что я могу сказать по представленной вами информации.

Comment: @metalurgus не катит на сервере, только локально

Comment: Так, как вы не приводите никаких деталей, то я не вижу ни одной причины хранить изображения локально. Или уточните, что и как вы с ними собираетесь делать, или довольствуйтесь моим ответом.

Comment: @metalurgus это будут картинки для CardView которые будут подгружаться в приложении при выборе определенных разделов и будут выстраиваться список. Если они будут грузится с сервера то информация с карточек теряет смысл т.к. ее с таким же успехом можно посмотреть в интернете.

Comment: добавьте их а zip архив, который покладите в Assets, и при первом запуске извлекайте

Comment: @metalurgus т.е. вы предлагаете распаковывать их в какую-то папку в телефоне  ? А они не начнут отображаться в галерее ?

Comment: зависит от папки, к которую их извлекать. Например, в `Context.getExternalFilesDir(null)` не будут. Также, вы, например, можете использовать какое-то другое расширение файлов (не `png`, а  `myapp` например). В этом случае куда бы вы их не извлекли, они не будут попадать в галерею.

Comment: @metalurgus а что будет если их просто оставить в drawable ? Или как есть постоянно извлекать из Assets?

Answer (score 3):

Я бы написал сервер на php, создал бы базу данных и создал бы таблицы - разная категория - разная таблица с картинками.

Вы с android приложения обращаетесь к серверу, сервер достает картинки из БД MySql для определенного раздела ( для запросов советую использовать библиотеку Retrofit 2 в связке с Gson ) и выдает ответ Json с url-ами картинок.

Клиент(android приложение) парсит эти url и загружает их, далее идет работа с CardView(картинки должны там отобразиться), все отображение делается в RecyclerAdpater, который вы должны написать самостоятельно.

Для того, чтобы решить проблему расхода огромного количества трафика, сделайте пагинацию(постраничная загрузка) и обязательно сделайте кэширование(сохранение скачанных картинок в локальной БД).

Comment: не подходит сервер мне